# Is it possible to move attachments between cards on different lists in Trello?

Tags: trello, attachment

Another member of the team added an attachment to the wrong card in Trello.

Is it possible to move this attachment to the correct card on another list (same board) without downloading, deleting, and re-attaching it?

Answer (score 6):

There is not (currently) a way to move an attachment from one card to another without going through the download, delete, re-attach process you've described.

Answer (score 2):

1. When displaying the card with the attachments to want to move, open another window of your browser (e.g. `ctrl-n` in Firefox).
2. On the new window, open the card to receive the attachments.
3. For each attachment, click on its `Open in New Tab` link.
4. Drag and drop the pictures into the receiving card.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link of the attachment (via usual right/ctrl click means) in the card with your attachment and then in the destination card, click attachments and paste the link.

Comment: That does not display the attachment (eg. a picture) as it would normaly. Instead it just displays it as "Link" attachment.